# default argument для функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы

Нужно написать функцию , которая производит массив с числами от 0 до N-1
к примеру arr(7) = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
При условии arr() => [ ] должен выдаваться такой результат, а не TypeError: arr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

пример arr(5) => [0,1,2,3,4]

arr(0) => []

arr()=> []
В моем коде выдается ошибка когда значения n нет.

```
def arr(n):
    array = []
    if n is None:
        return []
    for i in range(n):
        array.append(i)
    print(array)
    return array
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код. Уточните вторую половину вопроса. Каком условии? Приведите [mre] для такой ошибки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
def arr(n=0):
    return list(range(n))

print(arr(5))
print(arr(0))
print(arr())
```